# Check if elements in an array are inside of another array

Tags: c++, arrays

So If I have these two arrays:

`int array1[] = {1, 2 ,3};`

`int array2[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

How do I check if `1, 2 and 3` from array1 are in array2?  `

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do know that Python code is actually wrong?

Comment: @UnholySheep Probably is. Haven't touched python in so long.

Comment: In that case you should probably remove that statement about Python completely, as it is misleading (and in fact straight up wrong - Python does not have built-in syntax to check if one list is part of another).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::includes`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes):

```
if (std::includes(std::begin(array2), std::end(array2),
                  std::begin(array1), std::end(array1)) {
    // array2 includes array1
}
```

This requires the arrays are sorted, which yours are. Also, if they are sorted with some custom comparator, you must pass that to `std::includes` as well.

It is worth pointing out that I use your arrays the "wrong" way round; the algorithm expects its first range to be the larger one.

Comment: Thank you, looks easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection). It requires the arrays to be sorted using the same comparator, though.

example from cppreference:

```
std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
std::vector<int> v2{        5,  7,  9,10};
std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());

std::vector<int> v_intersection;

std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
                      v2.begin(), v2.end(),
                      std::back_inserter(v_intersection));
for(int n : v_intersection)
    std::cout << n << ' ';
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=a1e6503a6051c8c3)